# Calculate average wait & turn around times of a process

Tags: scheduling

Hi I am having trouble understanding exactly how wait and turn around times are calculated, I am learning this in preparation for an exam and I do have a past paper for this however the marking schemes do not explain where the values are coming from here is the question:

```
An operating system has two process priority levels, 1 and 2. Three new
processes, A B and C, arrive at the same time in that order with the
following characteristics

A
----------
Quanta Required 20

Priority 1    
----------

B
----------
Quanta Required 30

Priority 1
----------

C
----------
Quanta Required 40

Priority 2
----------

Calculate the average Waiting Time and average Turn-Around Time if:

a)normal Round Robin scheduling is used

b)a modified Round Robin scheduling which gives priority 1 processes a
double quantum and priority 2 processes a single quantum whenever they
are scheduled

c)What advantages or disadvantages has the algorithm described in (c)
compared to a Priority Queue scheduling?
```

The answers only show calculations with no explanation to the best of my understanding:

```
Average Wait Time = Sum of Process Finish times / Number of Processes

Average Turn Around = Sum of Process Start Times / Number of Processes
```

Is this correct or is there a better way to calculate this any help is much appreciated

Comment: The calculations for average wait time and average turn around are calculated by the formulas you've posted, and your class presumably studied Round Robin and Modified Round Robin scheduling. If you can't figure out how to answer the three questions asked, ask your instructor for help.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to check the formulas were correct